# merge same array index according to key and build a new array

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.5

I am trying to merge array index such as
011,021,031, 012,022,032, 013,023,033, 014,024,034 .

```
$temp = array();
foreach($samplearray as $key => $val){
    foreach($val as $key1 => $val1){
       //what should logic here     
    }
}
```

**sample array**

```
$samplearray = array ( "AA"  => array ( 0  => array ( "created by" => "011",
                                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                                ),
                                1  => array ( "created by" => "012",
                                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                            ),
                                2  => array ( "created by" => "013",
                                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                            ),
                                3  => array ( "created by" => "014",
                                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                            )               
                                ),
                "BB"  => array ( 0  => array ( "created by" => "021",
                                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                            ),
                                1  => array ( "created by" => "022",
                                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                            ),
                                2  => array ( "created by" => "023",
                                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                            ),
                                3  => array ( "created by" => "024",
                                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                            )               
                                ),
                "CC"  => array ( 0  => array ( "created by" => "031",
                                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                            ),
                                1  => array ( "created by" => "032",
                                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                            ),
                                2  => array ( "created by" => "033",
                                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                            ),
                                3  => array ( "created by" => "034",
                                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                            )               
                                )
                );
```

**Required output**

```
$newArray = array ( 0  => array ( "created by" => "011",
                                    "date" => "12-03-14",
                                    "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                ),
                    1  => array ( "created by" => "021",
                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                ),
                    2  => array ( "created by" => "031",
                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                ),
                    3  => array ( "created by" => "012",
                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                ),              
                    4  => array ( "created by" => "022",
                                    "date" => "12-03-14",
                                    "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                ),
                    5  => array ( "created by" => "032",
                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                ),
                    6  => array ( "created by" => "013",
                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                ),
                    7  => array ( "created by" => "023",
                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                ),
                    8  => array ( "created by" => "033",
                                    "date" => "12-03-14",
                                    "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                ),
                    9  => array ( "created by" => "014",
                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                ),
                    10  => array ( "created by" => "024",
                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                ),
                    11  => array ( "created by" => "034",
                                "date" => "12-03-14",
                                "time" => "12.00 pm"
                                ),                          
                );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually its quite simple. The hint is already in the title. `array_merge()`:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($samplearray as $key => $batch) {
    $newArray = array_merge($newArray, $batch);
}
```

To follow that special format, you could shift them each time until the `$samplearray` runs out.

Example:

```
$newArray = array();
while(true) {
    foreach ($samplearray as $key => &$batch) {
        $newArray[] = array_shift($batch); // shift each batch
    }

    if(empty($batch)) { // if it runs out, stop!
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @PuzzledBoy oh okay, i'l draft another one in just a bit

Comment: @PuzzledBoy check my revision

Comment: GR8 thankx... i also want to be strong in array and looping..:) please guide me..

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$temp = array();
foreach($samplearray as $key => $val){
   foreach($val as $key1 => $val1){
       $temp[] = $val1;
   }
```